# Request mp3 audio file from mysql using php

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, mp3

Hi I'm new to Php and I'm using this sample code to read some simple text data from mysql then request the data for an IOS app. If I want to request mp3 audio files how can it be done?: 
[Here's how the mp3 row looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWSkn.png)

```
<?php 

require("connect.php"); 

$db = mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ("Could not connect to mySql"); 
mysqli_select_db($db, $dbName) or die ("Could not select database"); 

$query = "select * from mydata"; 

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $row_set[] = $row; 
}

echo trim(json_encode($row_set));

mysqli_close($db); 

?>
```

Comment: You can encode as string the file. Then add as column info to $row. In practice :   $row["str_file_mp3"] = file_get_contents($row["path_mp3"]);     during the cycle before assign to $row_set[] so it will be passed for encode to json.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, can you please give a full example as a response below?

Comment: What does this question have to do with MP3?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 

require("connect.php"); 

$db = mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ("Could not connect to mySql"); 
mysqli_select_db($db, $dbName) or die ("Could not select database"); 

$query = "select * from mydata"; 

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $row["str_file_mp3"] = file_get_contents($row["path_mp3"]);
    $row_set[] = $row; 
}

echo trim(json_encode($row_set));

mysqli_close($db); 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I keep getting this error on the IOS Side : The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: And what's "str_file_mp3" and "path_mp3"?

Comment: i supposed your last column name was "path_mp3" for example. The "str_file_mp3" column is the new column wich i wanted to use for mp3 encoding into string but since you already face the problem maybe you have to convert it into another format like bytes. Where do you pass  the json?